# vb aspx page in jquery ui dialog, but only one code behind call works

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

javascript code looks something like this.

```
    select.dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: true,
        width: 800,
        height: 400,
        modal: true,
        appendTo: "form",
        close: function () {

            }
        }
    });


 $("a[id$='selectClient']").on({
        "click": function (event) {
            select.load('/website.aspx?Id=' + blockId).dialog('open');

            return false;
        }
    });
```

so the page load up fine in the dialog, but I can only call a code behind function once, the second call doesn't work.

Comment: Is `select` element parent of `a[id$='selectClient']`

Comment: select is an empty div on the first page, a[id$='selectClient'] is a linkbutton on that same page.